# visual c# problems with return in a method

Tags: c#

I found this code to search for a registry key, it works fine if i set it to void and have it pop up a window using messagebox.show , and i see the key it found. but, if i change it to return a string, the compiler fails with "not all code paths return a value" if i try to set a string in the method called "reg_result" and return it, i am returning the value to a string variable that calls the method.

```
string reg_result2 = Search_For_Registry_Keys(Registry.Users, search);

private static string Search_For_Registry_Keys(RegistryKey rk, string search)
 {
     string reg_result = "";
     if (rk.SubKeyCount > 0)
     {
         foreach (var temp in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
         {
             if (temp.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
             {
                 reg_result = (String.Format(rk.Name + "\\" + temp));
                 MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Match Found In Registry Key {0} Present At Location {1}", temp, rk.Name + "\\" + temp));
                 return reg_result;

             }
         }
         foreach (var temp in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
         {
             try
             {
                 if (rk.OpenSubKey(temp).SubKeyCount > 0)
                 {
                     Search_For_Registry_Keys(rk.OpenSubKey(temp), search);
                 }
             }
             catch
             {
             }
         }
     }

 }
```

I then tried the following by putting a 2nd return after the if statement and that got rid of the compiling error about "not all code paths return a value", but that didn't seem to help as then the method would never return when i stepped through it  until it reached the end of it's searching, so I'm little lost on how to fix this?? yes i am newbie. I would think i my first code would work and i only need one return for when i find the result i am looking for... :)

Comment: Suppose the key wasn't in the registry. What should the function return?

Comment: Additionally, beware of using empty catch blocks.  They can mask exceptions that you may need to be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this (comments indicate changes):

```
private static string Search_For_Registry_Keys(RegistryKey rk, string search)
 {
     string reg_result = "";
     if (rk.SubKeyCount > 0)
     {
         foreach (var temp in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
         {
             if (temp.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
             {
                 reg_result = (String.Format(rk.Name + "\\" + temp));
                 MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Match Found In Registry Key {0} Present At Location {1}", temp, rk.Name + "\\" + temp));
                 return reg_result;

             }
         }
         foreach (var temp in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
         {
             try
             {
                 if (rk.OpenSubKey(temp).SubKeyCount > 0)
                 {
                     // Added and changed lines here
                     string retVal = Search_For_Registry_Keys(rk.OpenSubKey(temp), search);
                     if (!retVal.Equals(""))
                     {
                         return retVal;
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch
             {
             }
         }
     }

     // Added this line
     return reg_result;
 }
```

Note what I've done: if no key is found at all, then you return `""` (the value initially assigned to `reg_result`). Also, when you recurse on a subkey (in the second `foreach` loop,) and you *do* find a result, that result is immediately returned.

Whenever you have a method that promises to return a value, you have to ensure that all code paths through it either a) actually return a value, or b) throw an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you define that a function returns a value (by stating the type of the return value) you have to return a value in every single case, not only when you find what you're looking for, but also when you DON'T find what you're looking for.  Put a `return reg_result`; as the last line of your function, and it should work.  Of course, you may want to change the value you return if you want some indicator other than the empty string that you didn't find what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you should create an empty string at the top of your method

```
var retValue = string.Empty;
```

Then change this `return reg_result` to this

```
retValue = reg_result;
```

Then at the end of you method outside all ifs and for ect.

```
return retValue;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Big edit:

Ignore what I posted; it was nonsense. Just see dlev's answer, it's much better!